# Inyección de dependencia en Asp.net Core usando Blazor

Tags: blazor, inyeccion-de-dependencias, directivas

Estoy tratando de entender bien la inyección de dependencias y veo en algunos casos (Blazor)
que se utiliza al principio del componente:

```
@inject MyHtmlHelper Html
```

En otros casos con el constructor que es lo más común:

```
   private readonly IMyHtmlHelper _html;
   public MyClaseContructor(IMyHtmlHelper html)
   {
      _html = html;
   }
```

y en otros casos directamente en una propiedad:

```
   [Inject]
   public IMyHtmlHelper html {get; set;}
```

Mi duda es si las 3 formas son lo mismo o hay diferencias con las instancias creadas.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea es la misma, es obtener el objeto de la dependencia.

La diferencia es mas bien en que puedes utilizar y que es lo que no puedes utilizar. Existen 2 partes: cliente y servidor (host). Por otro lado depende donde lo vas utilizar (ficheros .razor o .cs).

1. `@inject MyHtmlHelper Html` Solo puedes utilizar en ficheros .razor. Este formato es el que mas se utiliza en el lado cliente.
2. `public MyClaseContructor(IMyHtmlHelper html)` Este formato lo tienes que utilizar en ficheros .cs, que no son clases parciales de .razor. Por ejemplo lo podrias utilizar en un servicio que accede a base de datos, como servicio no tiene parte visual en .razor, tendrias que insertar la dependencia en su constructor. Este formato es el que normalmente se utiliza en el lado servidor.
3. `[Inject] public IMyHtmlHelper html {get; set;}` este formato puedes utilizar en los componentes que tengan o no tengan .razor. Este formato se utiliza sobretodo cuando creas componentes solo con c# sin uso de razor, por ejemplo si quieres reinventar componente InputText no te hace falta usar razor, pero si usas dependencia la insertarias con este metodo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entendí.